# Is $(0,...,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the unique critical point of the linear system of constant coefficients?

Tags: systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

If I've got the following differential linear homogenous system of constant coefficients

$$x_1'(t)=a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n $$
$$x_2'(t)=a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+...+a_{2n}x_n$$
$$... $$
$$x_n'(t)=a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+...+a_{nn}x_n.$$

Can I say that its unique critical point is the point $(0,...,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

---

Substituting, we can see clearly that $(0,...,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a critical point. But my doubt is, is it the only one?

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the coefficients. You can rewrite the problem in vector-notation as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}' = A\mathbf{x}
\end{align*}
with the coefficient matrix $A$. Then every $\mathbf{x}\in \ker(A)$ is a critical point. So wether $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the only critical point depends on the rank of $A$.

Comment: And if we suppose that $detA\neq 0$? then can we say that $0$ is the only one?

Comment: Yes, in that case $0$ is the only one